# DevArt dotConnect for Oracle: EF Mapping TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE to DateTimeOffset

Tags: oracle, entity-framework, devart, dotconnect

Using Devart dotConnect for Oracle (8.2.103), when trying to build a EDMX model (Database first) with EF5, I can't find a way to get a TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE column to be mapped into a DateTimeOffset instead of DateTime.

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have answered to you at our forum: http://forums.devart.com/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=28974.

Comment: As stated in that forum post, since dotConnect for Oracle 8.3, this behaviour has been changed and now it works perfectly